# Iterate through named ranges in a worksheet by cell / range reference order?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet of the below format but instead of "X_Name" being in the worksheet the headers "Sum1","Sum2"... are in a named range called "X_Name".

[image]

I need to loop through each of the named ranges and add them to a dictionary.

However, I want to loop through the ranges in the order they appear in the spreadsheet instead of the alphabetic order of the named ranges, as I want to preserve the ordering.

In the below example my Dictionary would be A_Name:I2:K2 , B_Name:A2:C2 , C_Name:E2:G2.

However, I want: B_Name:A2:C2 , C_Name:E2:G2, A_Name:I2:K2

Currend code which gives unsorted dictionary:

```
For Each namedRangeStr In ws.Names
    'namedRangeStr needs to be converted to Range object
    
    Set namedRangeRng = range(namedRangeStr)
   
    basisDict.Add namedRangeStr, namedRangeRng
    
    
Next namedRangeStr
```

Comment: Loop through the cells then, not the `Names`?

Comment: I'm unable to loop through the cells as the actual table contains some named ranges / sub-tables I want to exclude.

Comment: Then exclude them.

Comment: This is picking up an output from another model and the address of the named ranges will be changing so I can't exclude by their address.

Comment: Good luck then. Another option is to write a custom sorting routine based on the `namedRangeRng.Column`.

Comment: You'll have to sort the namedranges (store them in an array) like BigBen says based on their position and then work from the array (you can leave out the ones you don't want) to fill your dictionary.